# JMeter + Git + Jenkins

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jmeter, allure

I have performance tests made by Jmeter , then i loaded all of them on github and run on Jenkins.
All cool except one thing - i can't easily see summary report or folder report.
After each build run I can enter in console output and view way to html report to each test , but i think it's hard to find to users and I can't even see summary statics.

So - could I and how make summary report on Item element page in jenkins , or how can i just show in same item element page in Jenkins local directory (named like 'results') ?

If i have only one test - it's no problem . I've used performance plugin test and it show all graphics , but for now i have more than one performance test.

P.S. Interesting to know - can i use Allure report just for know how many performance tests pass and how many failured ?

Answer (score 0):

you could add [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) to Jenkins to get JMeter support.

Once the plugin is added you can add a post-build (Jenkins -> Your Project -> Configure ->  “Add post-build action” dropdown) action on Jenkins to produce the report.

Ref: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins

Comment: Thanks, but i wrote about it previously. 
Anyway may be you know, could i used performance test for many reports?(for 1 i could and used it befroe)

Comment: By the way - one of way decision - use HTML Publisher. 
And here another question - how i can configure Jenkins on Dynamic way?

I mean i have results in package like : 
`\target\jmeter\reports\nameOfTJmeterTaste_dateANdTimeWhenTestDone`
Can i put some extra symbol/s to avoid data like: 
`\target\jmeter\reports\nameOfTJmeterTaste_*`

??